# Need help finding a corresponding distribution

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, monte-carlo, boxcox-transformation

I made a Monte Carlo based hypothesis test, which starts comparing N values in M simulations to a confidence interval, giving me a binary N*M matrix. Then I calculate the percent of values equal to 1 for every simulation.
So the final M values I'm going to use for the hypothesis test are between 0 and 1.

However, I can't fit the values to any distributions I know using Kolmogorov-Smirnov, even Box-Cox transformation (car package in R) fails to give me a normal distribution. Below are two pictures of the non-transformed distributions to help visualize.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

What are the suggested distributions for my case study? Preferably those I can fit to any single mode or bi-modal data from my procedure and not only the example distribution.

Comment: looks like a mixture of two Betas...

Comment: Used fitdistrplus::fitdist in R to find the shape1 and 2 for beta distribution, didn't pass in any of them.